# Prove a bipartite graph is connected

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

I have the following [Bipartite graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Segc0.png), how can I prove that it is connected?

[image]

I have been searching the Internet for hours but couldn't find a solution, I need a mathematical method to prove it is connected (not looking for solutions such as run DFS or BFS).

I am looking for a (sufficient) condition on a bipartite graph in terms of the vertex degrees, number of edges etc. that implies the graph is connected

Comment: By inspection it is connected. Are you interested in bipartite graphs with some particular structure and/or special characteristic?

Comment: @vonbrand  For example while searching I found that for some graphs if each vertex has a degree >= ( n − 1 ) / 2  then the graph is connected. I'm looking for such proof.

Comment: why don't  you ask *that* then?! We might be wizards here, but not mind readers...

Comment: @user5132182 Consider editing your question to make it clearer for answerers. To most readers "a method to prove" something implies a procedure. Instead, you seem to be looking for a (sufficient) condition on a bipartite graph in terms of the vertex degrees, number of edges etc. that implies the graph is connected. If so, feel free to copy and paste into the question :-).

Comment: @Frentos I edited my question, do you know any way ?

Comment: @user5132182 I edited my question 3 hours ago to add the answer I found :-).

Answer (score 4):

These two graphs have the same degree sequence:

[image]

The one on the left is your (connected) graph, whereas the one on the right is disconnected.  So, you're not going to find a mathematical sufficient condition for connectedness based on degree sequences alone.

Also, keep in mind that conditions like "if each vertex has a degree $\geq ( n − 1 ) / 2$ then the graph is connected" are also algorithmic.  To verify connectedness, the reader still needs to check each vertex has degree $\geq ( n − 1 ) / 2$.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've tagged this under "matrices", let's use the adjacency matrix $A$.

$A_{ij}^n$ (i.e. entry $ij$ in $A^n$) represents the number of walks of length $n$ between vertices $i$ and $j$.  In a connected graph, the maximum distance require to get from any node to any other is $V-1$ where $V$ is the number of vertices. So to test whether a graph is connected, you can compute $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{V-1}A^{i}$: if there are no $0$ entries, the graph is connected.  If there are $0$ entries, it's not.

**Edit**: The requirement seems to be not for a method of proof as originally requested but for a sufficient condition on a bipartite graph to ensure connectedness. [This math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858426/connected-bipartite-graph), (result #4 of Googling "bipartite graph connected") shows that if each vertex has degree $\frac{n}{4}+1$ then the bipartite graph is connected.

Comment: adjacency matrix, not incidence

Comment: I want a more general proof, read my comment above

Comment: @sfaria thanks - have corrected it!

Comment: In the given example, $$A^5=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}^5=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 4 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 10 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 9 & 5 \\ 5 & 9 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 4 & 10 & 9 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 4 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}.$$  It has $0$ entries.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones You're correct - we need the sum. Will edit.

Comment: @Frentos Thanks for your reply, i was wondering is there a general proof that any matrix that looks similar to the above matrix (for example if i add 1 at (2,3) and symmetry at (3,2) ) it will stay connected ?

Comment: @user5132182 Adding 1s to the matrix is equivalent to adding an edge to the graph: if the graph was connected before then adding a new edge will leave it connected. In the particular matrix above, row1=A, row2=B, row3=C on your original graph. Adding 1s at (2,3) and (3,2) is the same as adding an edge between B and C; the new graph is still connected but no longer bipartite.